# How do you make a gridded div be filled with an image without it affecting any other divs?

Tags: html, css, image

I tried lots of things, but it won't work.
Code which may be the cause: (CSS)

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#article-image-section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.i-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

I do have it on [codepen](https://codepen.io/ArchDud3/pen/MWPyqdJ)

Full code - does include something completely irrelevant: (CSS & HTML)

```css
body {
  background-color: #212121;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

h1, h2, h3,
a, p, span {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #587;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nav-section {
  padding: 3rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}

#nav-logo-section,
#nav-link-section {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-link-section {
  gap: 10rem;
}

#nav-social-section,
#nav-contact-section {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#nav-logo-section {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border-left: 0px;
}

#nav-social-section {
  font-size: 30px;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.article-section {
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.article-nav-section,
.article-description-section {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

.article-nav-section {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-left,
.nav-right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 14%;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.nav-right {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

.article-description-section,
.article-title-section {
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

article {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#article-image-section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.i-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2172e4ad38.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav>
  <div id="nav-logo-section" class="nav-section">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="favicon.jpg" width="50px" height="auto">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="nav-link-section" class="nav-section">
    <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#">TESTING</a>
  </div>
  <div id="nav-social-section" class="nav-section">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-google-plus"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="nav-contact-section" class="nav-section">
    <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<main>
  <article>
    <div class="article-image-section article-section">
      <img class="i-img" src="add-image-in-flutter-hero.webp">
    </div>
    
    <div class="article-description-section article-section">
      <p>
        Hello!
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="article-title-section article-section"></div>
    
    <div class="article-nav-section article-section">
      <div class="nav-left">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-right">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
</main>
```

Diagram of current & expected output (Requested by Youssouf)
[image: First half of image is a diagram is naved current output with 3/4 filled by "div 1 (image-div)", 1/4 (lenghwise) "div 2", 1/4 (height) "div 3", 1/16 in the corner "div 4". A box contained inside of "div 1" is labelled as boudaries. The same is for the second half, but the divs are contained inside the boundaries box.]

Comment: Can you clarify a little, like what's the expected final output?

Comment: Please cut out the irrelevant stuff from your snippet, but ensure it actually shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Don't rely on a codepen, it may disappear in future, making your question useless for other readers.

Comment: @AHaworth There has already been a snippet, not?

Comment: @InSync yes there is a snippet, but didn't look minimal to me.

Comment: will the articles be a slideshow, so only one article appears on the page making the body height doesn't exceed `100vh` ?

Comment: Yes I am using the articles as a slideshow. @Abdelrahman

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution, you will find adjustments made in css code commented with `/* adjustment */` with explanations. I believe your current design is for desktops, to have a better look, see the result in full page.

I will walk through some of the important adjustments:

- Removing `article-section` height set to `100%` because that make the `article-section` height same as `article` height while `article` contains multiple sectoins (every one of them taking its full height value would result in overflow).
- Specifying `overflow:hidden;` for `article-section` to make sure all grid cells content don't overflow, not only image section.
- Specifying `flex: 1` to main and `overflow:hidden;` to make sure it fills remaining content of the body without overflowing it.

Take in mind, here, i'm using just one article as the slideshow functionality isn't implemented yet.

```css
body {
  background-color: #212121;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  /* adjustment */ 
  /* giving margin 0 and padding 0 to ensure body doesn't affect content */
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
a,
p,
span {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  
  /* adjustment (minor) */ 
  /* to make sure navbar items can be accessed when 
  they overflow in x direction while body overflow is hidden
  */
  overflow-x:auto;
}

/* adjustment (minor) horizontal scrollbar styling for nav */
nav::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: .4rem;
}
/* Track */
nav::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Handle */
nav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

/* Handle on hover */
nav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}


.nav-section {
  /* adjustment (minor) */ 
  /* smaller padding for navbar to for display 
  (something of your choice, but you should consider their values  
  in responsive design) */
  
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

#nav-logo-section,
#nav-link-section {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-link-section {
  gap: 10rem;
}

#nav-social-section,
#nav-contact-section {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#nav-logo-section {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border-left: 0px;
}

#nav-social-section {
  font-size: 30px;
}

main {

  /* adjustment */ 
  /* giving flex 1 for main makes its height take remaining 
  space of the body height (body height - nav height)
  and prevent it from overflowing by making overflowing hidden*/
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.article-section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  
  /* adjutment */
  /* prevent article sections from overflowing their grid cell containers 
  and that for all sections not only the image section
  */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.article-nav-section,
.article-description-section {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

.article-nav-section {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-left,
.nav-right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 14%;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.nav-right {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

.article-description-section,
.article-title-section {
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

article {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
  
  /* adjutment */ 
  /* preventing article to overflow parent main */ 
  overflow: hidden;
}

#article-image-section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  /* overflow here is redundant since it's specified in the article-section
  if you want, remove it*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.i-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="nav-logo-section" class="nav-section">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="#" width="50px" height="auto">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="nav-link-section" class="nav-section">
    <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#">TESTING</a>
  </div>
  <div id="nav-social-section" class="nav-section">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-google-plus"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="nav-contact-section" class="nav-section">
    <a href="#">
      CONTACT
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
<main>
  <article>
    <div class="article-image-section article-section">
      <img class="i-img" src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1673014201877-64e88f4b5542?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2ODE2MTg4ODc&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85">
    </div>
    <div class="article-description-section article-section">

      <p>
        Hello!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="article-title-section article-section">

    </div>
    <div class="article-nav-section article-section">
      <div class="nav-left">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-right">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```